# Supabase: update/delete entries in auth.users from the client

Tags: javascript, postgresql, rest, supabase

I've learned from
[supabase docs](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/v1/auth-api-deleteuser) and [this discussion](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/1284) that we can pass in a `service_role key` to the `supabaseClient` so to bypass RLS (row-level-security), and therefore be able to access/modify data in the auth.users table client-side.

For now, I'm using a second instance of the supabase client to perform updates to the auth.users table when needed.

```
import { createClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js"; // version  "2.0.4"

const {
  VITE_PROJECT_URL,
  VITE_ANON_PUB,
  VITE_SERVICE_ROLE,
} = import.meta.env

export const supabase = createClient(VITE_PROJECT_URL, VITE_ANON_PUB); // 1. regular client

export const supabaseAdmin = createClient(VITE_PROJECT_URL, VITE_SERVICE_ROLE) // 2. admin client
```

This approach works great in Dev mode: I'm capable of updating/deleting entries in auth.users alright.

```
// works in Dev, Error in Prod
 const { data } = await supabaseAdmin.auth.admin.deleteUser(customer.auth_id);

// example from docs: slightly different syntax 
const { data: user, error } = await supabase.auth.api.deleteUser(
  '715ed5db-f090-4b8c-a067-640ecee36aa0'
)
```

However, this is not working in production. Getting the following error: `Uncaught Error: supabaseKey is required`.

That said, my question is:
How should I deploy code that interacts the auth.users table?
Will I need a server function to do only this? (Already trying it BTW, having that same problem `supabaseKey is required` though

Answer (score 1):

For the record, managed to have it fixed !

The error was caused by bad environment variables setup on my hosting provider (netlify). Totally a stupid mistake, I'm the only one to blame

However, I learned a bit on my way debugging it and would like to share it here for reference

**mistake #1** 
Double check env variables setup in whatever platform you're using to host the app (netlify, vercel, etc.), this can save you hours of useless frustration...

**mistake #2**  
Supabase docs say it all the time: Don't use your `service_role` in frontend code. So if you don't have a backend, use cloud functions for the job. Pretty much all providers nowadays have this feature.

**mistake #3**  
not setting the `access-control-allow-origin` header in the server-side function respose. This should spare you from problems with cors